# How to get the execution time(time to get response) and api of rest api in nodejs using middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I want to get the execution time(time to get response) of rest api in nodejs for each api that is running on the server,their last execution time and api performance time.

Answer (score 0):

Before the first route, add in a new middleware that will log the timing for you.

```
function logResponseTime(req, res, next) {
    // Get the start time before it hits the route
    const startHrTime = process.hrtime.bigint();
    // Finish is emitted when the response is sent
    res.on("finish", () => {
        // Get the end time
        const endHrTime = process.hrtime.bigint();
        // Calculate the time in ms and log it
        const elapsedTimeInMs = Number(endHrTime - startHrTime) / 1000000.0;
        logger.info(req.method + " " + req.originalUrl + " " + elapsedTimeInMs);
    });

    next();
}
// Add in as middleware. Needs to be before any routes
app.use(logResponseTime);
```

This will log something like:

```
GET https://my.url.com/ 180.3567
```

Comment: Can I also know who hits this api previously and what was his system IP Address?

Comment: How this will work can you explain GET https://my.url.com/ 180.3567

Comment: You would need to store who the previous user was somewhere. And the IP address is from req.ip (but make sure you read about [Express Proxies](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

And the GET line is what will be logged by the code I provided above